# Data should display only with respect to the button i clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, division

i am having six buttons in a table,after clicking each button the data related to button should display,if i click another button previous data should disappear and only data with respect to that button should display.I am Using div. please help me how to do it.

Comment: Please show your code what you have tried so far..

Comment: Please post your code or share fiddle.

Comment: For your own research here is a starting point for a possibility. https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide div first then you can show that according to button Id.
Please see   [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgwugk5y/3/)

```js
$("#bt1").click(function(){
$(".hide").hide();
$("#id1").show();
})
$("#bt2").click(function(){
$(".hide").hide();
$("#id2").show();
})
$("#bt3").click(function(){
$(".hide").hide();
$("#id3").show();
})
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" id="bt1">button1</button></td>
         <td><button type="button" id="bt2">button2</button></td>
         <td><button type="button" id="bt3">button3</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="id1" class="hide">Button1</div>
<div id="id2"  class="hide">Button2</div>
<div id="id3"  class="hide">Button3</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgwugk5y/3/